# Cannot import Xgboost in Anaconda Jupyter notebook- Windows7

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I have installed Xgboost for my Windows 7 64-bit. Xgboost works.

But I can not import xgboost from Anaconda Jupyter Notebook with ERROR code 127.

Environment:

- Python 2.7.12
- Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)

[image]
[image]